# Saving the matplotlib 3d rotating plots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Hi does anyone know if there is a way of saving the matplotlib 3d rotating plots in a format which allows them to be still rotated? Perhaps a particular program?

Code is:

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as p
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

A=transpose(genfromtxt("Z:/Desktop/Project/bhmqntm-code/RichardsonRK4.csv", unpack=True, delimiter=','))

T=A[:,0]
X=A[:,1]
P=A[:,2]

fig=p.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X,P,T,s=1,cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('P')
ax.set_zlabel('T')
p.show()#I would like this to be something like savefig('Z:/Desktop/Project/bhmqntm-code/plot3d_ex.png') but with a file ending of a program that would save the 3d capability
```

I'm not sure if a program which does this actually exists but if anyone knows of one it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: maybe pickle it, and then you can re-open in another python session.

Comment: Hi, I got the plots to pickle and reload eventually but the reloaded plots do nto rotate. :( Has anyone had success with this or am I doing something worng?

Comment: sorry, on further consideration (and any testing) this now seems like a bad idea (I couldn't even get the `figure` object to pickle).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Have you had any luck finding a method to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think matplotlib can do it.
The solution I found is to make graphs to display them in the browser. For example use [plot.ly](http://plot.ly).

An example: https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/#3d-plotting